# Efficient mysql query for product catalogue

Tags: php, mysql

So i have a website with a product catalog, this page has 4 product sliders one for recent products, another for bestsellers a third one for special offers.

Is it better to create a query for each type of slider, or should I get all products and then have php sort them out and separate them into three distict arrays one for each slider?

Currently I am just doing

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE deleted = 0
```

For testing.

Comment: In general, the fewer round trips to the database the better. There are exceptions. But that should be your starting point.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost always best to refine the query so that it just returns not only the records you actually need, but also only the columns you really need. So, in your case this would look like

```
SELECT id, description, col3 
FROM products 
WHERE deleted = 0 
AND -- conditions that make it fit in the proper slider
```

The reason is that it also costs resources (time and bandwidth) to transport a result set over to the processing program and processing time to evaluate the individual return records, and thus the "cost" of the query will evolve with the table size, not with the size of the dataset you actually need.

Just an example, but let's suppose you want to create a top 10 seller list, and you have 100 items in story. You'll retrieve 100 records and retain 10. No big deal. Now, your shop grows and you have 100000 items in store. For your top 10 you'll have to plow through all of theses and throw away 99990 records. 99990 records you'll have the db server read and transfer to you, and 99990 records you have to individually inspect to see whether it's a top 10 item.

As this type of query is going to be executed often, it's also a good idea to optimize them by indexing the search columns, as indexed searches in the db server are much faster.

I said "almost always" because there are **rare** cases where you have a hard time expressing in SQL what you actually need, or where you need to use fairly exotic techniques like query hints to force the database engine to execute your query in a reasonably efficient way. But these cases are fairly rare, and when a query doesn't perform as expected, with some analysis you'll manage to improve its performance in most cases - have a look at the literally thousands of questions regarding query optimization here on SO.

Comment: While there's nothing technically wrong here, and it's full of useful and true information- I feel it rather misses the point.

Comment: @Stawberry with the limited detail in the question it's the best I could do - I tried to 1) explain the scaling problems associated with this kind of "bulk requests" 2) the fact that frequently used queries should be backed by indexes and 3) that if the db seems to perform poorly, you need to analyze what's going on, most performance issues can be solved with standard means or an improved query. That should at least get OP started in their research. What big point do you feel I missed?

Comment: Erm, the question. Whether 'tis nobler to execute one query or three

Comment: @Strawberry OP stated `should I get all products and then have php sort them out and separate them into three distict arrays one for each slider` where the sliders seem to be recent products, bestsellers and so on, each normally small subsets of the total items available. And, probably almost constant in size (eg "Top 10" exactly specifies the size of a list) whereas the inventory will quite likely grow over time. Roundtrip problems are an entirely different class of problems (and in this kind of scenario, rather irrelevant imo).